# Application of the inverse function theorem on a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, diffeomorphism, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:U \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ continue in a convex set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$. If $\langle{f'(x)(v),v}\rangle>0$ for all $x \in U$ and for all $0 \neq v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism of $u$ on its image.

So first, i wanna show that f'(x) is an isomorphism, particulary i have to show f'(x) os bijective, for inyectivity i have to see that the kernel of the linear transformation is zero, as f is linear transformation its derivative is the same, but i don't understant clearly the relationship between the kernel and the inner product.

The next step is proof the surjectivity but with the dimensional theorem is clear, and when f'(x) is isomorphism i can use the inverse function theorem to proof f is diffeomorphism, taking into account that f is a linear transformation in particular is $c^{1}$ class.

Comment: A linear map $L : \mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ is surjective if and only if it is injective (rank-nullity formula).

Comment: Yes but i don't know anything about de linear transformation, just $\langle f'(x)(v),v \rangle >0$ in other words, i can't assume the surjective of the linear map $f$ can i?

Comment: $f$  is not linear! But $f'(x)$ is and $f'(x)v =0$ is only possible for $v=0$, so $f'(x)$ is injective for any $x$. Therefore, $f'(x)$ is surjective for any $x$.